# How do I pass an image from Vue.js to PHP to save it as a BLOB into a database?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, vue.js, mysqli

This sounds simple enough but trust me I wasn't able to find a viable solution to this. I have a Vue.js project which uses PHP as a backend to retrieve/save data from and to a database. I've already set up AJAX using Axios to submit content from various `<input>` fields on the page. However, I'm having huge issues doing the same with images file uploads. Currently, all the images are stored inside the database as MEDIUMBLOBs. I've created a form inside the HTML code with a Vue.js event listeners :

```
    <div v-for="(gallery, i) in galleryMeta">
        <form @submit.prevent="editData('gallery', gallery.Id, i)">
            <div class="row no-gutters">
                <div class="col-xl-6 col-md-5 col-sm-4 col-12 pb-sm-0 pt-sm-0 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-md-start justify-content-sm-center">
                    <div class="d-flex flex-column py-3 pl-sm-0 pl-4">
                        <h6 class="font-normal text-brand-primary pb-1 pl-md-0 pl-sm-4">Title :</h6>
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-md-start justify-content-sm-center">
                            <input type="text" class="border-radius" v-model="gallery.Title">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-12 pb-sm-0 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-sm-end justify-content-center">
                    <div class="d-flex flex-sm-column pr-lg-0 pr-sm-3">
                        <label class="btn btn-brand-primary font-bold py-2 my-sm-0 my-2" :for="'gallery-'+gallery.Id">EDIT</label>
                        <input type="file" :id="'gallery-'+gallery.Id" style="display: none;" accept="image/jpeg,image/png,image/webp" @change="pickData">
                        <button class="btn btn-brand-secondary font-bold px-lg-5 px-3 py-2 my-2 mx-sm-0 mx-2" @click="editData(gallery.Id, i)">UPLOAD</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Simply put, there is one `<input>` which is the image title and two buttons – one to pick a file and the second to upload it (the upload button runs the final method that is supposed to pass the data using Axios to PHP).

This is the Vue.js code to handle the AJAX request. The `pickData` method just gets the file from the event, and the `editData` should handle the submission of the file along with its title :

```
methods:{
    pickData: function (){
        this.Image = event.target.files[0];
        },
    editData: function (Id, i){
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', this.Image);
        axios.post('ajax.php', formData, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            }
        })
        axios.post('ajax.php',{
            request: 12,
            Id: Id,
            Title: this.galleryMeta[i].Title
        })
        .then(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        })
        this.galleryMeta[i].File = this.Image
    }
}
```

Then I'm trying to get the AJAX request values from within PHP. I first decode the data since it's encoded as JSON and match it with the proper request:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$request = $data->request;
```

Here's is the if statement from `ajax.php` to handle the request :

```
if($request == 12){
    $id = $data->Id;
    $title = $data->Title;
    $file = file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
    $stmt = $db -> prepare("REPLACE INTO images (id, title, file) VALUES(?, ?, ?);");
    $stmt -> bind_param('iss', $id, $title, $file);
    $stmt -> execute();
}
```

Nothing fancy, just binding the `Id` and `Title` to insert it into the database. I expect the file to be in sort of like a DOM of multipart/form-data as it was told on various websites that you can directly point to the file with `$_FILES['file']` from PHP to retrieve the file as defined in the Axios JavaScript request. After selecting the file and clicking on the 'UPLOAD' button I'm presented with the following output in the browser console from Axios (which is also outputted twice by the way, not sure whether that's normal behavior, and I've ensured that there isn't any other request with the same number that could've possibly also been executed):

```
Object { data: "<br />\n<b>Warning</b>:  Undefined array key \"file\" in <b>C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\COMPANY\\ajax.php</b> on line <b>28</b><br />\n<br />\n<b>Warning</b>:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in <b>C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\COMPANY\\ajax.php</b> on line <b>28</b><br />\n<br />\n<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught ValueError: Path cannot be empty in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\COMPANY\\ajax.php:28\nStack trace:\n#0 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\COMPANY\\ajax.php(28): file_get_contents('')\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in <b>C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\COMPANY\\ajax.php</b> on line <b>28</b><br />\n", status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest }
```

However when I edit my PHP code to this :

```
if($request == 12){
    $id = $data->Id;
    $title = $data->Title;
    $file = file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
    $txt = fopen('response.txt', 'w');
    fwrite($txt, "$file");
    $stmt = $db -> prepare("REPLACE INTO images (id, title, file) VALUES(?, ?, ?);");
    $stmt -> bind_param('iss', $id, $title, $file);
    $stmt -> execute();
}
```

I get the same error HOWEVER the content does get written into the TXT file which should not be possible as I understand it since `$file` should be undefined since the array key of `'file'` is supposed to be undefined right? Is there anything I can do to view which keys for `$_FILES` have been defined or that are available? I know you can achieve this with `$_POST` for instance by doing `var_dump($_POST)` nonetheless, doing so with `$_FILES` just dumps the binary content representation for that file (so that bunch of junk that I'm trying to save it to the database). I've copied this output that's been written to `request.txt` and manually inserted it into an HTML `<img>` and the image did render, so it is indeed the actual file that's been saved to the TXT file. What is going on here? How can I hand the file properly to PHP? The main part is that I need to be able to save it to the database properly, which with this error does not happen, and the query fails to execute properly. I could technically save the `var_dump` of it and use that since I'll always only be working with a single file at a time, but that is such a dirty hack that I'm ashamed to even mention it… Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: `doing so with $_FILES just dumps the binary content representation for that file`...well that shows you it's been populated, and there should be other fields shown too. What else do you want to know from it?

Comment: `which is also outputted twice `... well that'll be because you're calling it twice. You're running axios.post twice. That'll probably also be why it works but still errors